# Using Enum for DropdownList: Missing a using directive or assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with an enum property in ASP.NET Core.

Here is the model (viewmodel):

```
namespace Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels
{
    public class StoreIndexData
    {
        [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }    

        [Display(Name = "Distrito")]    
        public int DistrictID { get; set; }
        public string DistrictName { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(tiendacadenaenum))]
        public tiendacadenaenum tienda_cadena {get;set;}
    }
    public enum tiendacadenaenum
        {
        [Display(Name = "Cencosud")]
        Cencosud,
        [Display(Name = "Cinerama")]
        Cinerama,
    }
}
```

And here is part of the view:

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
@using Application.Models

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="tienda_cadena" class="cold-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="tienda_cadena" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<tiendacadenaenum>()">"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="tienda_cadena" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

There is a problem showing here:

```
Html.GetEnumSelectList<tiendacadenaenum>()">
```

claiming there is missing a using directive or an assembly reference. Any idea on how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Use the fully qualified name - `Html.GetEnumSelectList<Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.tiendacadenaenum>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `@using Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels` to the view.

Also it is recommended to use the naming convention as this make it easier for others to read your code, specifically use PascalCase for enum names, property names, namespace names, and method names.

So the code should look something like that:

```
namespace Application.Models.ApplicationViewModels
{
    public class StoreIndexData
    {
        [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }    

        [Display(Name = "Distrito")]    
        public int DistrictId { get; set; }
        public string DistrictName { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(TiendaCadenaEnum))]
        public TiendaCadenaEnum TiendaCadena { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TiendaCadenaEnum
        {
        [Display(Name = "Cencosud")]
        Cencosud,
        [Display(Name = "Cinerama")]
        Cinerama,
    }
}

@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
@using Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels
@using Application.Models

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TiendaCadena" class="cold-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="TiendaCadena" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TiendaCadenaEnum>()">"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="TiendaCadena" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```